# the program is stuck while giving output

Tags: c++, arrays, output, arr

I dont know why the program is failed to give output, This is the code to find number of zero's
in a given array

```
     #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int b=0 , a;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        a=arr[j];
        while(a==0)
        {
            b=b++;
        }
        
    }
    cout<<b;
}
```

Comment: As soon as `a == 0` you start incrementing `b` and you'll never finish as `a` remains the same `0`. By the way it's a good opportunity to learn how to work with a debugger

Comment: Beyond that, `b=b++;` is undefined behavior. If you just want to increment `b`, that's simply `b++;`.

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
if (a==0) //you had a while here
{
  b++;
}
```

Since you are not changing the value of 'a' inside the loop, it gets stuck inside the while and this leads to an infinite loop!

Comment: Do. Or do not. There is no try.

Comment: Note to asker: You still still need a `while`. It just needs a different exit condition. The above answer needs to go in the `while`

Comment: @user4581301 i can't see any need for a while loop? Changing to if would seem to give the desired behaviour?

Comment: It looks like you mixed up `b++` and `b = b + 1`

Comment: @AlanBirtles somehow I completely missed the wrapping `for` loop.

Comment: but in geeks for geeks it is showing compilation error {prog.cpp:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id before { token}                            the result is coming perfect in my pc

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int b = 0, a = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a = arr[j];
        if (a == 0) //here you used while use if as you are checking the condition every iteration of loop.
        {
            b++;
        }
    }
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but in geeks for geeks it is showing compilation error {prog.cpp:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id before { token}                            the result is coming perfect in my pc

Answer (score 0):

just do this in the j for loop. you don't need any `a` variable or anything

and also runtime variable arrays  are not allowed in C++ use dynamic arrays or `vectors`

```
for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]==0){
            b++;
        }
        
    }
```